# Conditional Multiselect data

Tags: kendo-react-ui

What is the best way to list data in multiselect conditionally(depends on the data selected)?
For example:

```
data = [...laboratoryUsers, ...technicianUsers, ...receptionUsers]
```

if a laboratory user is selected, only laboratory users would be found on the multiselect options.

and so on.